# Proof of $\lim_{x \to \infty}\tan x/x$ does not exist

Tags: calculus

There is an answer for this question as follows:

If we approach to infinity with the sequence $a_{n}=n\pi$ then limit is zero, on the other hand if we approach with the sequence $b_{n}=\pi/2+n\pi-1/n^2$ then limit is infinity.

I can not understand the process that is described.

Comment: Just a thought from what you wrote. Limit is defined as uninque number (point). But if there are two infity sequences reaching two different points, which one would be the limit? Therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: What, that limit if we use the second sequence is $\infty$? The process is that a limit exists if and only if all sequential limits exist and are equal.

Comment: @quapka I understand from your hints this limit if it exist, must be equal to limit of the sequences $tan(a_{n})/a_{n}$ and $tan(b_{n})/b_{n}$ so i must check these sequences limits.

Comment: @silbira Perhaps rewriting the $tanx=\frac{sinx}{cosx}$ may help: Consider the limit $\frac{sinx}{x}.secx$ with $x$ to infinity. The first limit exists, but how about the second limit?

Comment: My main idea to ask this question is that explicit proof for such limits:$\lim_{x \to \infty} sinx$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty} cosx$ does not exist. Intuitively it is said that they 'pertub' when x tends to infinity between -1 and 1.

Comment: But from formal way this is not good. It seems to me the above process is formal way to decide why limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go to definitions. What does it mean for $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ to exist? It means that there exists some $L\in \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty, \infty\}$ such that for **any** sequence $(x_n)$ (where each $x_n$ is in the domain of $f$), that has the property that $lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=\infty$, we have that $lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x_n))=L$. This may be slightly hard to parse, so let's put it in words. All this definition is really saying is that regardless of how we approach infinity (this corresponds to the "for **any** sequence with the property that $lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=\infty$" part of the definition) The values of $f$ along this path should approach the same value (this corresponds to the "$lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x_n))=L$ regardless of $(x_n)$" part of the definition). Now let's look at your example of $\tan(x)/x$. If we approach infinity with the sequence $a_n = n\pi$, then we see that the values of $f$ along this path approach zero. Symbolically, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=0$. If on the other hand we approach infinity with the sequence $b_n = \pi/2 + n\pi - 1/n^2$, we see $lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)=\infty$. Thus the value that $f$ approaches depends on the path we use to approach infinity. The definition tells us that the limit only exists if the value $f$ approaches is independent of the path we choose. So the limit cannot exist.

Comment: I know if f is continuous then you can take the limit inside. For the converse is continuouty necessary also?

Comment: Continuity doesn't really enter the discussion here; limits can exist even for functions that are nowhere continuous.

Comment: You are right. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response, but something else led me to the function $\frac{\tan{x}}{x}$ and its limit as $x \to \infty$. I came across this post only now.

We can, in fact, prove a more general result for the function $f(x) = \frac{\tan{x}}{x}$ than what is said originally in the post. We can prove the following:

Given any $l \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of real numbers, $\langle b_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = l$.

To see this, let $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{\alpha n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \neq 0$ be any (fixed) real number. Then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \epsilon_n = 0$. Now define $b_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi - \epsilon_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$, and you can prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = \frac{\alpha}{\pi}$. Given any $l \in \mathbb{R}$, $l \neq 0$, if you now choose $\alpha = \pi l$, then it is clear that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = l$.

When $l = 0$, let $b_n = n \pi$. Then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = 0$.

Also, if you let $\epsilon_n = \pm \frac{1}{n^p}$ where $p > 1$, you can prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = \pm \infty$.

What this argument shows is that you can "adjust" the limit of $f(b_n)$ to anything you want. Thus there is no unique limit.