# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin x\tan x }{x^3+x^2} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin x\tan x }{x^3+x^2}
> $$

---

I have tried using series but couldn't solve the problem

Comment: I guess you need a definition of "limit as $x$ approaches infinty" when the function is undefined for a sequence of values going to infinity.

Comment: i think the Limit doesn't exist

Comment: that limit does not exists.  takes $x= n\pi$ and change with pi/2 you will to different limits

Comment: You don't need series. The set of limit values of $\tan x$ is $(-\infty,+\infty)$ so there is no limit

Comment: The book where I got this question had a finite answer but not a detailed solution

Comment: What was its answer?

Comment: Is the answer 0?

Comment: The options were -2,-1,-1/2,-3

Comment: @SagarChand  No 0 is not the answer

Comment: Probably a typo (maybe it was meant to go to 0). If the limit is to infinity, the tan function visits all real values repeatedly, in fact, it has poles, so there can be no limit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\frac1x$. Then we have $x=\frac1y$,  $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin \frac1y\tan \frac 1y }{(\frac1y)^3+(\frac1y)^2}$. Now let's show that $$\lim_{y\to0}\sin \frac1y$$ does not exist. We will write:
$${Y_{n1}}=\frac1{n*\pi} = \frac1\pi,\frac1{2\pi},\frac1{3\pi},\frac1{3\pi},\frac1{4\pi},....-->0; sin(\frac1{Y_{n1}})=0 (always);\lim_{y\to0}\sin \frac1{Y_{n1}}=0$$
$${Y_{n2}}=\frac2{(4n+1)*\pi} = \frac2{5\pi},\frac2{9\pi},\frac2{13\pi},....-->0; sin(\frac1{Y_{n2}})=1(always);\lim_{y\to0}\sin \frac1{Y_{n2}}=1$$
$${Y_{n3}}=\frac2{(4n-1)*\pi} = \frac2{3\pi},\frac2{7\pi},\frac2{11\pi},....-->0; sin(\frac1{Y_{n3}})=-1(always);\lim_{y\to0}\sin \frac1{Y_{n2}}=-1$$
So, in one pointwe have 3 different limits. But it is not possible. It means that limit does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation
$$
\sin x\tan x=x^k
$$
for $k$ a positive integer. It's not difficult to show that each of these equations admits an increasing sequence of solutions $(x_{k,n})$ so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{k,n}=\infty
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin x_{2,n}\tan x_{2,n}}{x_{2,n}^3+x_{2,n}^2}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_{2,n}+1}=0
$$
whereas
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin x_{3,n}\tan x_{3,n}}{x_{3,n}^3+x_{3,n}^2}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_{3,n}}}=1
$$
we can conclude that the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments given are of intuitive nature.

The limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \sin{x}$ does not exist but $\sin{x}$  is a bounded function.

So for the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$  we can use Squeeze Theorem and prove that it is $0$. Look at the Graph.

[Sin[x]/x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcB7Z.jpg)

The limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \tan{x}$ does not exist but $\tan{x}$  is an unbounded function.

So the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{\tan{x}}{x}$ Does not exist. Also look at another post [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038926/proof-of-lim-x-to-infty-tan-x-x-does-not-exist). Here is the Graph:

[Tan[x]/x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG31L.jpg)

Clearly the function $\displaystyle \frac{\sin{x}\tan{x}}{x^3+x^2}$  is an unbounded function. Here is the Graph:

[(Sin[x]Tan[x])/(x^3 + x^2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFD5o.jpg)

So intuitively $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{\sin{x}\tan{x}}{x^3+x^2}$ Does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin x\tan x }{x^3+x^2}
$

$\sin x\tan x 
=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}
\to \infty
$
when
$x\to 2\pi n+\pi/2
$
and
$\sin x\tan x 
=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}
\to 0
$
when
$x\to 2\pi n
$
so the limit does
not exist.